# SQL Server 2000 complains about comparing TEXT/NTEXT columns but columns are VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with a table that looks like this:

```
ModifyTime datetime
CompanyID smallint
ProductID smallint
ComponentID int
Disposition varchar(10)
Note text
NoteType varchar(256)
```

This query fails:

```
UPDATE NoteTable
SET Disposition = 'Modified'
WHERE Disposition = '' 
    AND CompanyID = 10
    AND ProductID = 13
    AND ComponentID = 1
    AND NoteType = 'Customer'
```

The error is:

> *The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.*

There is a `TEXT` column but it's not involved in the query at all. The two text-like fields are both `VARCHAR`.

I regularly do `JOIN`s on the `NoteType` field and order by `Disposition` without this error.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure about the column data types? And what happens if you change NoteType LIKE 'Customer' ?

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table? Could you post the whole error message, including the `Msg xxx, ...` etc. portion when you run this update in Query Analyzer / Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, when simplifying the question to ask here I factored out the actual cause of the problem.

In reality the UPDATE happens in an ASP app, and the value I represented here as 'Customer' is passed as a parameter to a prepared statement. In creating the parameter, I used adLongVarChar with a length of 256 instead of adVarChar with a length of 256. So it was actually the constant against which I was comparing the VARCHAR(256) NoteType column that was the problem. When I fixed the parameter type to the prepared statement, the problem went away.

Sorry to bother you and thanks for your help. :-)